# Python CGI isn't doing anything. Did I misconfigure something?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, apache, cgi

I'm trying to learn web dev, and I've run into a problem. This feels like it ought to be dead simple, and yet, here I am. 
I want a Javascript function on a webpage to call a Python script on the server and log the result.

I'd guess I probably configured my server wrong in some way. For reference, I'm using the Bitnami LAMPP server on Amazon Lightsail.
As far as I know, I configured Apache correctly for CGI. In httpd.conf I already have the ScriptAlias for /cgi-bin/, I've enabled mod_cgid, I've added +ExecCGI to the options for the directory and added the cgi-script handler.

In my cgi-bin folder, I have cgi.py:

```
#!usr/bin/env python
import cgi
print("Hey, look, the CGI worked")
```

and in my htdocs folder I have /cgitest/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>CGI</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Check the console
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        $.get("/cgi-bin/cgi.py", function(data){
                console.log(data);
        });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But all I see in the console is "ready!"
Other tests reveal that it's never getting into the function in get().
I'm wondering whether I've configured something on the server wrong, or whether there's something wrong with my code.

Update: Got the status code for my request. I'm getting 403 Forbidden when cgi.py is in the same directory as the webpage, and 500 Internal Server Error in the /cgi-bin directory.

Comment: Does it work if you just browse to the URL without javascript? If it works when you go without javascript I would guess it's because you're not sending the headers section of HTTP which you've to do yourself when doing CGI. `print('HTTP 1.0 200 OK\n\n')` should be it iirc

Comment: I just made that change; I'm getting 403 Forbidden or 500 Internal Server Error depending on where I put my CGI.

Comment: The 500 might be a good indication! That could mean that it's running. You should check the error log for Apache and see if it has any juicy details for you :)